# Sizing customized button to size of content

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've created the following very simple button style:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="content" Value="0.4"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I want to use it to make small buttons that only shows a little icon with no border that is clickable.

So I have this icon, with dimensions 16 x 16 pixels, called icon.png.

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource SimpleButton}">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Program;component/Art/icon.png" />
</Button>
```

The button is placed in a horizontal StackPanel.

Now the button shows up with dimensions 34x34. How can I make sure the button is sized to the size of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource SimpleButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Program;component/Art/icon.png" Stretch="None" />
</Button>
```